# Rails - Finding the count of user's who have created posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-1.9.3

I wish I could give you guys some code but this question is more of a math problem and doesn't need code to solve.

I'm trying to find a number. The number shows the total count of users who have created Posts. Say my app has 25 posts and those posts come from 4 different users, then the count equals 4. How can I get this count??

The count is for this

```
@collections = Collection.all
```

Finding the number of users who have created a Collection.

Thanks so much.

Comment: That's giving me a wrong number actually. Thank you though!

Comment: Collections belongs to users? Try `Collection.select(:user_id).distinct.count`, I suppose your collection model has a field `user_id` to store id of user which collection belongs to.

Comment: That's it @KienThanh. Thank you both for helping!

Comment: Yep, @KienThanh solution is much better :)

Comment: With pluck method :) `Collection.pluck('DISTINCT user_id').count`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Collection.distinct.count(:user_id)
```

This will execute a count query and only return the number of unique users who created a Collection.